# Unity 5: access/modify AnimatorController from C# script in editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I'd like to write an editor menu item that accesses currently open animation controller and destroys/creates/modifies animation transitions.

Basically, I need to iterate through all animation states/clips in currently open animator controller, and based on their names create transitions with specific and adjust playback speed for all clips.

I have this code snippet:

```
        UnityEditorInternal.AnimatorController ac = GetComponent<Animator>().runtimeAnimatorController as UnityEditorInternal.AnimatorController;
        int numLayers = ac.layerCount;

        for(int i = 0; i<numLayers; i++){
            UnityEditorInternal.AnimatorControllerLayer layer = ac.GetLayer(i);
            Debug.Log ("Layer " + i + " is: " + layer.name + " and has " + layer.stateMachine.stateCount + " states");
            UnityEditorInternal.StateMachine sm = layer.stateMachine;
            for(int n = 0; n<sm.stateCount; n++){
                UnityEditorInternal.State state = sm.GetState(n);
                Debug.Log ("State " + state.name + " is " + state.GetHashCode());
                UnityEditorInternal.Transition[] list = sm.GetTransitionsFromState(state);
                for(int j = 0; j<list.Length; j++){
                    UnityEditorInternal.Transition transition = list[j];
                    Debug.Log ("Transition: " + transition.name + " is " + transition.GetHashCode());
                }
            }
        }
```

However, it does not compile on Unity5 (written for Unity 4, most likely), and I'm unsure how to get a hold of currently open AnimatorController using Unity 5 functions.

The animator controller class seems to be defined as `UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorController`, but I can't figure out how to grab currently open one.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to access AnimatorController via inspector context menu. That's not very convenient (because to process the whole controller, I need to select it in project view first), but it works.

```
public class AnimImportTools: MonoBehaviour{
//.....

    [MenuItem("CONTEXT/AnimatorController/Make transitions immediate")]
    private static void makeTransitionsImmediate(){
        UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorController ac = Selection.activeObject as UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorController;
        foreach(var layer in ac.layers){
            foreach(var curState in layer.stateMachine.states){
                foreach(var transition in curState.state.transitions){
                    transition.duration = 0.0f;
                    transition.exitTime = 1.0f;
                }
            }
        }
    }
//.....
}
```

If someone knows better way to do it - i.e. add menu in more accessible location OR run this script from main menu (and get currently open animatorcontroller from there), I'm all ears.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to your answer i came up with the following:

```
    Animator animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    string assetPath = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(animator.runtimeAnimatorController);
    AnimatorController controller = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<AnimatorController>(assetPath);
```

This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Slightly hacky way to get to reflectively get current AnimatorController in open Animator window (it should be focused):

```
static AnimatorController GetCurrentController()
{
    AnimatorController controller = null;
    var tool = EditorWindow.focusedWindow;
    var toolType = tool.GetType();
    var controllerProperty = toolType.GetProperty("animatorController", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (controllerProperty != null)
    {
        controller = controllerProperty.GetValue(tool, null) as AnimatorController;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("EditorWindow.focusedWindow " + tool + " does not contain animatorController",tool);
    }
    return controller;
}
```

Works as of my current Unity version (5.2.2p4).

Then I was combining that with using the Selection.objects to find selected states to make my tools with it.